# Ruby regex | Match enclosing brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern to match particular sets of text in my string.

Let's assume this is the string `^foo{bar}@Something_Else`
I would like to match `^foo{}` skipping entirely the content of the brackets.

Until now i figured out how to get all everything with this regex here `\^(\w)\{([^\}]+)}` but i really don't know how to ignore the text inside the curly brackets.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try matching to anything between brackets, like this: `foo\{.*\}@Something_Else`

Comment: Why it has to be regex solution?  Can you not do using string manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

This is the final solution:

```
puts script.gsub(/(\^\w+)\{([^}]+)(})/, '[BEFORE]\2[AFTER]')
```

Though I'd prefer this with fewer groups:

```
puts script.gsub(/\^\w+\{([^}]+)}/, '[BEFORE]\1[AFTER]')
```

## Original answer

> I need to replace the `^foo{}` part with something else

Here is a way to do it with `gsub`:

```
s = "^foo{bar}@Something_Else"
puts s.gsub(/(.*)\^\w+\{([^}]+)}(.*)/, '\1SOMETHING ELSE\2\3')
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/DXCtiF)

The technique is the same: you capture the text you want to keep and just match text you want to delete, and use backreferences to restore the text you captured.

The regex matches:

- `(.*)` - matches and captures  into Group 2 as much text as possible from the start
- `\^\w+\{` - matches `^`, 1 or more word characters, `{`
- `([^}]+)` - matches and captures into Group 2 1 or more symbols other than `}`
- `}` - matches the `}`
- `(.*)` - and finally match and capture into Group 3 the rest of the string.

Comment: We are getting closer, thanks! But this is not really what i needed. Basically i need to replace the ^foo{} part with something else :)

Comment: Yes, to be more precise, script.gsub(/(\^\w+)\{([^}]+)(})/, '[BEFORE]\2[AFTER]')     Thank you!

Comment: Well, the technique is the same: you capture the text you want to keep and just match text you want to delete, and use backreferences to restore the text you captured.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to match `^foo{}` by a single match against a regex, it is impossible. A regex match only matches a substring of the original string. Since `^foo{}` is not a substring of `^foo{bar}@Something_Else`, you cannot match that with a single match.